# In Laravel 10 , Spatie backup package 8.5 ...when run

Tags: php, laravel-10

`Artisan::call('backup:run'); $output = Artisan::output();`

Its giving me error .....

Starting backup...

Dumping database invoicedata...

Backup failed because: The dump process failed with a none successful exitcode.

Exitcode

========

2: Misuse of shell builtins

Output

======

Error Output

============

mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)" when trying to connect

.

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\spatie\db-dumper\src\DbDumper.php(194): Spatie\DbDumper\Exceptions\DumpFailed::processDidNotEndSuccessfully(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process))

#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\spatie\db-dumper\src\Databases\MySql.php(143): Spatie\DbDumper\DbDumper->checkIfDumpWasSuccessFul(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), 'C:\xampp\htdocs...')

#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob.php(280): Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\MySql->dumpToFile('C:\xampp\htdocs...')

#3 [internal function]: Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup{closure}(Object(Spatie\DbDumper\Databases\MySql), 'mysql')

#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Arr.php(558): array_map(Object(Closure), Array, Array)

#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Collections\Collection.php(777): Illuminate\Support\Arr::map(Array, Object(Closure))

#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob.php(249): Illuminate\Support\Collection->map(Object(Closure))

#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob.php(189): Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->dumpDatabases()

#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob.php(163): Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->createBackupManifest()

#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Commands\BackupCommand.php(65): Spatie\Backup\Tasks\Backup\BackupJob->run()

#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(36): Spatie\Backup\Commands\BackupCommand->handle()

#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()

#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))

#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))

#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(662): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)

#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(211): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)

#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(326): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))

#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(180): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))

#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\spatie\laravel-backup\src\Commands\BaseCommand.php(28): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))

#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(1096): Spatie\Backup\Commands\BaseCommand->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))

#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(324): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Spatie\Backup\Commands\BackupCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))

#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(175): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))

#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(162): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput))

#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(400): Illuminate\Console\Application->call('backup:run', Array, NULL)

#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(355): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->call('backup:run')

#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\app\Http\Controllers\DataBaseBackupController.php(46): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('call', Array)

#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\DataBaseBackupController->createBackup()

#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('createBackup', Array)

#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(259): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\DataBaseBackupController), 'createBackup')

#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(205): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()

#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(806): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()

#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\app\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory.php(25): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#36 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#37 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#38 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#39 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#40 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#41 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#42 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#43 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Session\Store), Object(Closure))

#44 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#45 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#46 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#47 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#48 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#49 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#50 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(805): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

#51 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(784): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#52 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(748): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))

#53 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(737): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#54 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#55 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#56 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\Features\SupportDisablingBackButtonCache\DisableBackButtonCacheMiddleware.php(19): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#57 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Livewire\Features\SupportDisablingBackButtonCache\DisableBackButtonCacheMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#58 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#59 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#60 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#61 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#62 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#63 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#64 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#65 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#66 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#67 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#68 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#69 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#70 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#71 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))

#72 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#73 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

#74 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#75 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\public\index.php(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

#76 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\invoiceshop\server.php(21): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')

#77 {main}

Backup failed because: The dump process failed with a none successful exitcode.

Exitcode

========

2: Misuse of shell builtins

Output

======

Error Output

============

mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)" when trying to connect

```
`type here`
```